# Which lens is better for portraits the canon ef 17-40mm f/4 or the canon ef 24-105mm f/4?

Tags: lens, canon

I can't decide between the two so your opinion would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: On what type camera? APS-C or FF?

Comment: What type of portraits? Environmental? Full body? Half torso? Tight head shots?

Answer (score 11):

If your primary purpose is shooting portraits neither of these two lenses is an ideal candidate. There are quite a few other options that are much better suited to doing portraits. For full frame the typical candidates would be any of the 50mm primes, 85mm f/1.8, 100mm f/2, and 135mm f/2 primes or the 24-70mm f/2.8 and 70-200mm f/2.8 zooms. With an APS-C camera the short list would include a fast 35mm prime as well. The larger apertures of the primes and fast zooms open up possibilities that the f/4 zooms can't equal. Most of the time primes and fast zooms also provide better image quality than f/4 zooms. This is certainly the case with any of the lenses listed above compared to the two lenses considered in the question.

If you are budget limited and need a versatile zoom that can also function as a general all-purpose walkaround lens then it depends upon what sensor size you are shooting as much as anything else.

With a full frame camera the EF 24-105mm f/4 iS L is the better choice hands down. It provides a more varied focal length range with some very useful angles of view, has Image Stabilization that is effective for about 3 stops when shooting static subjects with a handheld camera, and has better overall image quality than the EF 17-40mm f/4 L.

The water gets a little murkier when the camera is an APS-C body. The 17-40mm gives an angle of view that is equivalent to a 28-64mm lens on FF. The 24-105mm gives an angle of view that is equivalent to a 38-168mm lens on FF. For portraits the 24-105mm still offers the most useful focal lengths, but the general usefulness as a general purpose walkaround lens is sacrificed.

I own both of these lenses and frequently shoot with them on FF cameras. In the focal lengths where they overlap I go pretty much exclusively with the 24-105mm. The only thing the 17-40mm offers over the 24-105mm is the wider angle of view and lighter/smaller form factor.

Comment: I agree. If the choice is between those two I would choose the 24-105 as well. APS-C or not. But if the goal is ONLY ( or Mainly) for portrait, I'll just choose none of those lenses.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think the 24-70 is acceptable yet the 24-105 is not. Is it about the lens itself rather than the focal length?

Comment: @CrazyDino It is mostly about the maximum aperture. The 24-70 f/2.8 will let twice as much light through as an f/4 lens. It will also allow much shallower depth-of-field which is often much desired for portraits.

Comment: I don't think I said either lens was "not acceptable". What I said was that there are other lenses that are much better suited to doing portraits than the two mentioned on the OP.

Comment: Apologies should have said better suited. Good point with the DoF.

Answer (score 0):

24 will become 36 and 105 will become 157 (considering 1.5x crop factor). So on a 24-105 you'll be able to get 50 mm (actual) focal length at around 35 mm, 85 mm (actual) can be achieved at around 57 mm and 105 mm (actual) can be achieved at 70 mm. These lengths are perfect for portraiture.

The F4 will give a very shallow depth of field at 105 mm when zoomed in to max. And the optics of the lens, the build quality and the positioning of the elements is very good of the EF 24-105mm f/4 ISL lens.
It's a very versatile all round standard zoom, which should suit most of the shooting styles.